# Quarantine for COVID? No! I am healthy!

Tags: word-usage

Suppose Mr. Zhang just got an forced-quarantine order and he says

> "I don't need any quarantine, I am quite healthy" [src](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/healthy)

or

> ... "I am in quite good health" [src](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/health)

or

> ... "I have quite good health" [src](https://www.scientificworldinfo.com/2018/05/health-is-wealth.html)

or

> ... "I'm having quite good health"

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has%20good%20health%2Cis%20healthy%2Chas%20a%20good%20health%2Cis%20in%20good%20health%2C%20health%20is%20good&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Chas%20good%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhas%20good%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHas%20good%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20healthy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20a%20good%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20in%20good%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chealth%20is%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhealth%20is%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHealth%20is%20good%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Chas%20good%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhas%20good%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHas%20good%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20healthy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20a%20good%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20in%20good%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chealth%20is%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhealth%20is%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHealth%20is%20good%3B%2Cc0) verifies some of the uses above.

Do native speakers say it that way?

Are they grammatically correct? Do they mean the same thing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

1,2 are fine. There may be differences of nuance.

Healthy goes with "fit and healthy". You can talk about healthy food or healthy lifestyles.

Good health is more to do with the absence of physical or mental disease.

3. is less good (and your source for three is not a good source) That isn't the usual idiom.

4 is not generally used.  It combines the unidiomatic "I'm having" (rarely used in the sense of "possession") with the unidiomatic "have good health"

The meaning of "quite" is subtle, as it can (depending on intonation, dialect, stress) mean both "slightly" or "completely".

Comment: Thank you. Does "fit" here mean "not too slim and not too fat"?

Comment: "...I am quite healthy" sounds idiomatic.

Comment: "fit" means what you are like if you go to the gym regularly.  Athletes are usually very fit.  You can be slim, but not fit if you don't do any exercise.